# Can I implement default initialization in protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, dry

I have a variety of classes that all conform to a single protocol and share the same initialization method. Is there a way to implement the initialization in the protocol? So I don't have to copy the code in every class. This is what I have so far

```
protocol someProtocol {
    init(data: Data)
}

class ObjectA: someProtocol {
    let data: Data
    required init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class ObjectB: someProtocol {
    let data: Data
    required init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do this as the protocol and protocol extension have no knowledge about the properties in the objects that conform to them and so you cannot initialise all the story properties.

I’m sure there are other runtime reason about type inference too but this one is probably the most simple to explain.

Comment: So I guess having a base class is the way to go for my case?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If every one of your classes has the same data then why not just have one class? I cannot say if a base class is the way to go as I have zero knowledge of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I feel like you are trying to use protocols for the wrong reason here. Try asking a question about the problem you are trying to solve. I am sure there will be people (including me) willing to offer help.